# A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property on continuation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, task

I'm struggling mightily with observing exceptions that happen on a task continuation. The scenario is that I make an api call within a task, and on the ContinueWith I check if the response is unauthorized, if so then I try to renew the auth token. If renewing the auth token succeeds then I retry the original task (api call), if it fails then I throw a custom AuthorizationFailedException to fail the task. The ContinueWith has a ObserveFailures extension method tagged to the end of it which is supposed to handle the Exception, however I'm still getting the exception not observed error, which crashes the app.

The code is complex, so I've tried to slim it down here:

Making the api call:

```
protected virtual void ExecuteResults<TResponse> (TaskCompletionSource<QueryResponse<TResponse>> tcs, Func<Task<QueryResponse<TResponse>>> queryTask, CancellationToken token) {
            QueryResponse<TResponse> result = null;
            RenewTokensIfRequired (() => queryTask ())
                .ContinueWith (t => {
                    try {
                        result = t.Result;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ServiceLocator.Current.Resolve<ILoggingService> ().Log (CommonEnums.LogLevel.Info, "BaseDataService ExecuteAndCacheResults, ex: " + ex.ToString ());
                        if (!tcs.Task.IsCompleted)
                            tcs.SetException (ex);
                        return;
                    }
                    tcs.SetResult (result);
                }).ObserveFailures (tcs);
        }
```

The wrapper task which handles renewing auth token if the api call was unauthorized, and throwing an AuthenticationFailedException if renewing the auth token fails:

```
    public static Task<QueryResponse<TResult>> RenewTokensIfRequired<TResult> (Func<Task<QueryResponse<TResult>>> taskProvider, Func<AuthorizationContext, bool> shouldRetry = null) {
                if (shouldRetry == null)
                    shouldRetry = (context) => context.AuthorizationLevel != AuthEnums.AuthorizationLevel.None;
                return taskProvider ()
                    .ContinueWith (t => RenewTokenContinuation (t, taskProvider, shouldRetry, 1)).ObserveFailures ();
            }

    static QueryResponse<TResult> RenewTokenContinuation<TResult> (Task<QueryResponse<TResult>> task, Func<Task<QueryResponse<TResult>>> taskProvider, Func<AuthorizationContext, bool> shouldRetry, int attemptsRemaining) {
                var response = task.Result;
                if (response == null || response.HasAuthenticationFailure) {
                    if (attemptsRemaining > 0 && shouldRetry (AuthorizationContext.Current)) {
                        var context = AuthorizationContext.Current;
                        if (context.AuthorizationLevel == AuthEnums.AuthorizationLevel.Session) {
                            DataService.Auth.RenewSessionTokenAsync ().ObserveFailures ().Wait (10.Seconds ());
                            return taskProvider ()
                                .ContinueWith (retryTask => RenewTokenContinuation (retryTask, taskProvider, shouldRetry, --attemptsRemaining)).ObserveFailures ()
                                .Result;
                        }
                        if (context.AuthorizationLevel == AuthEnums.AuthorizationLevel.Device) {
                            DataService.Auth.RenewDeviceTokenAsync ().ObserveFailures ().Wait (10.Seconds ());
                            return taskProvider ()
                                .ContinueWith (retryTask => RenewTokenContinuation (retryTask, taskProvider, shouldRetry, --attemptsRemaining)).ObserveFailures ()
                                .Result;
                        }
                    }
                    ResetAuthentication ();
                }
                return response;
            }

private static void ResetAuthentication () {
            // If we make it this far, then we need to throw an AuthenticationException because we couldn't refresh a token
            AuthorizationContext.Current.SessionToken = null;
            AuthorizationContext.Current.DeviceToken = null;
            throw new AuthenticationFailedException ();
        }
```

And then lastly, here is the ObserveFailures extension method, which is supposed to handle exceptions but seems to not be...

```
public static Task<T> ObserveFailures<T> (this Task<T> task, TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = null) {
            task.ContinueWith (t => {
                TaskActions.LogException (t.Exception);
                if (tcs != null)
                    tcs.TrySetException (t.Exception);
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            task.ContinueWith (t => {
                ServiceLocator.Current.Resolve<ILoggingService> ().Log (CommonEnums.LogLevel.Info, "The task was canceled");
                if (tcs != null)
                    tcs.TrySetCanceled ();
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
            return task;
        }
```

Here is the crash stack trace:

> Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable:
>   System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed
>   either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As
>   a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer
>   thread. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>   ---> 
>   RPR.Mobile.Shared.Exceptions.AuthenticationFailedException: Exception
>   of type 'RPR.Mobile.Shared.Exceptions.AuthenticationFailedException'
>   was thrown.   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskAuthorization.ResetAuthentication ()
>   [0x00017] in
>   /Users/justintoth/Documents/rpr-mobile/shared/Utility/Extensions/TaskExtensions.cs:310
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskAuthorization.RenewTokenContinuation[TResult]
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] task, System.Func`1[TResult]
>   taskProvider, System.Func`2[T,TResult] shouldRetry, System.Int32
>   attemptsRemaining) [0x0016b] in
>   /Users/justintoth/Documents/rpr-mobile/shared/Utility/Extensions/TaskExtensions.cs:272
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskAuthorization+<RenewTokenContinuation>c__AnonStorey2`1[TResult].<>m__0
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] retryTask) [0x0001e] in
>   /Users/justintoth/Documents/rpr-mobile/shared/Utility/Extensions/TaskExtensions.cs:261
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke
>   () [0x00027] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:207
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502

Any ideas?

Comment: Not helpful. How are these functions a monstrosity? Each function tackles a separate concern, which is the intent of functions.

Comment: No but the use of ContinueWith awfully nests your code, plus you are calling `.Result` so many places it hurts. No wonder your code is complicated and horrible to debug.